# Game App cannot run in Genymotion

Tags: genymotion

I am having trouble loading a game app on genymotion. The game is Star Wars Force Collection. I can load the game, get the splash screens, then it crashes.

I have done some research before I posted here. The possible problems found in the genymotion logcat file:

1. There was a line noting Google services was out of date, "Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4030500 but found 3225136"
2. Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000364 (code=1), thread 1796 (RefQueueWorker@)
3. W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(  280): setKernelCountSet(10040, 1) failed with errno -1
4. Some have pointed out ARM Translator problem and OpenGL.

Then again I'm really not sure the problem, and I want to post the logcat file here but I don't know how to attach it.

For problem 1, I have seen other thread here that may have fixed it with code, I'm not savvy enough for that and my Google is not updating itself.

That's about it. A few details about genymotion and the VM. I am running the latest version of genymotion and virtualbox. I am using the downloaded Custom image 4.3 as provided by Genymotion. I flashed the ARM Translation v1.1. I flashed the Gapps onto it, (I tried a higher version of Gapps to try and solve the problem, but that just made it crash) and then Star Wars Force Collection, most up to date version.

Also, worth noting that the app was running fine for v2.++, until an update to v3.++ made the game crash. I updated my graphics drivers to try and mend any graphics issues.

So there it is, any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: bunp? I'd give $50 for whoever that can get this app running on geny